# How to Send String as a Soap request in android

Tags: android, web-services

String id = array1[position];

how to send this id as a soap request in android

I mentioned webservice side coding below......pls help me...

```
public string GetOutletID(string outlet)

 {
            xDoc.LoadXml("<PMS></PMS>");
            XmlNode Root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

            XmlElement head = xDoc.CreateElement("EMENU");
            Root.AppendChild(head);

            XmlElement dt = xDoc.CreateElement("DATETIME");
            dt.InnerText = Date;
            head.AppendChild(dt);

            elem = null;
            elem = xDoc.CreateElement("ID");
            elem.InnerText = "1";
            head.AppendChild(elem);

            elem = null;
            elem = xDoc.CreateElement("REQTYPE");
            elem.InnerText = "OUTLETID";
            head.AppendChild(elem);

            elem = null;
            elem = xDoc.CreateElement("OUTLETID");
            elem.InnerText = outlet;
            head.AppendChild(elem);
            return xDoc.InnerXml.ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this example this may help.....................

```
public static final String SOAP_URL = "http://scrwash.com/WebService/MiWebService.asmx"; public static final String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

public static final String SOAP_METHOD_RegisterUser = "RegisterWithPhone";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION_RegisterUser = SOAP_NAMESPACE+SOAP_METHOD_RegisterUser;

public String getmUserName() {
    return mUserName;
}

public void setmUserName(String mUserName) {
    this.mUserName = mUserName;
}

public String getmPassword() {
    return mPassword;
}

public void setmPassword(String mPassword) {
    this.mPassword = mPassword;
}

public String doRegisteration() throws Exception {

String doRegisterationReply = RegisterUser(this.getmUserName(),this.getmPassword());
System.out.println(doRegisterationReply);
return doRegisterationReply;

    }


public static String RegisterUser(String userName, String userPassword) {

        String responce = null;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE,
                SOAP_METHOD_RegisterUser);

        PropertyInfo mUserName = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo mUserPass = new PropertyInfo();

        String xChg = userName.replaceAll("-", "");
        System.out.println(xChg);
        mUserName.setName("phone"); // Element at SOAP
        mUserName.setValue(xChg);

        mUserPass.setName("password"); // Element at SOAP
        mUserPass.setValue(userPassword);

        request.addProperty(mUserName);
        request.addProperty(mUserPass);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_URL);
        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_RegisterUser, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive LoginResult;
            LoginResult = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("=================Register User Results: "
                    + LoginResult.toString());
            responce = LoginResult.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responce;
    }
```